# extjs disable cell editing

Tags: extjs

How I can disable specific cell editing from xml data file?

like this:

```
<price disabled="true">9.37</price>
```

Please give me examples
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, to read attributes from XML response you need to include a field in your model that has a `mapping` config to the attribute, see [this post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?158026-Load-XML-with-attributes-in-a-store&highlight=xml%20attributes). In your case something like this:

```
Ext.define('yourApp.model.Price', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'price',     type: 'float'},
        {name: 'disabled',  type: 'boolean',  mapping: 'price/@disabled'}
    ]
});
```

It's been awhile since I've used XML response so you may have to play around with that a bit.

Then you should simply include a check in your gridpanel's [`beforeedit`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-beforeedit) event to  prevent editing if the record's `disabled` field is true.

If you are using the MVC pattern it would be something like this:

```
// controllers init function
init: function() {

    this.control({

        'yourgridpanel': {

            // prevent disabled edits
            beforeedit: function(plugin, edit) {

                if (edit.record.get('disabled')) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If you are not using an MVC pattern the handler would go something like this:

```
yourGridPanel.on('beforeedit', function(plugin, edit) {
    if (edit.record.get('disabled')) {
        return false;
    }
});
```